# Parallel stations in markup language

Tags: workflow, yaml

What is the best way to specify concepts of parallel stations in workflow design in markup language like YAML? Is there any other good alternative to specify it more declaratively in other markup languages?

Answer (score 0):

If each parallel station has a unique element that identifies it use mappings and those names, if they don't use sequences. In both cases make sure to mark what kind of object the map/sequence represents by tagging it with `!!ParallelStations`:

```
!!ParallelStations
name1:
  detail1: value1
  detail2: value2
name2:
  detail1: value3
  detail2: value4
```

with mapping or with sequence:

```
!!ParallelStations
- detail1: value1
  detail2: value2
- detail1: value3
  detail2: value4
```